# Usage of dash (-) in place of a filename

Tags: shell, command-line, utilities

For a command, if using `-` as an argument in place of a file name will mean STDIN or STDOUT.

1. But in this example, it creates a file with the name `-`:

   ```
   echo hello > -
   ```

   How can I make `-` in this example mean STDOUT?
2. Conversely, how can I make `-` mean a file named `-` in examples such as:

   ```
   cat -
   ```

Comment: Since I apparently have to have 50 reputation to comment directly... On the /dev/stdin /dev/stdout comment, AIX, which is a legitimate UNIX derivative does not have these pseudodevices. And, as a further comment, LINUX is not a UNIX derivative in any case. It is a POSIX-compliant workalike, and the most popular of the UNIX-ish OS's at this point, but make no mistake, this is no UNIX. But, the gist of the replies here are correct. The "-" notation is not interpreted as special by the shell, and is thus passed directly to each individual application as an ARG. If the application does not recogni

Comment: There are also `2>&-` construction, which means "close descriptor 2".

Comment: @user95873, what I suppose you wanted to say is: *while Linux is Unix-like, not every Unix-like (or true UNIX) is Linux*. The matter whether Linux is or isn't true UNIX (i.e. complies the Single UNIX Specification) doesn't have relation to /dev/std{in,out,err} issue. As /dev/std{in,out,err} is *added* feature, not *missing*.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Using `-` as a filename to mean stdin/stdout is a convention that a lot of programs use. It is not a special property of the filename. The kernel does not recognise `-` as special so any system calls referring to `-` as a filename will use `-` literally as the filename.

With bash redirection, `-` is not recognised as a special filename, so bash will use that as the literal filename.

When `cat` sees the string `-` as a filename, it treats it as a synonym for stdin. To get around this, you need to alter the string that `cat` sees in such a way that it still refers to a file called `-`. The usual way of doing this is to prefix the filename with a path - `./-`, or `/home/Tim/-`. This technique is also used to get around similar issues where command line options clash with filenames, so a file referred to as `./-e` does not appear as the `-e` command line option to a program, for example.

Comment: It's worth adding that `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` are universally available and can be used in place of the `-` convention.

Comment: Also in the `cat` case, using redirection instead of listing the argument might help: `cat <-`; however, it would be hard to mix and match that with concatenating more than one file at a time.

Comment: @jmtd: /dev/std{in,out} are not universally available. Not all unixes have it.

Comment: Interesting, I assumed they were part of POSIX (but can't confirm). They're present at least on Linux, the BSDs and Solaris.  Can you give an example of a modern UNIX that lacks them?

Comment: @camh Not sure if you got the notification, and this is a very, very old topic;  I'm not sure if you can, but I'm very curious if you know the answer to `jmtd`'s question? :)

Comment: @jmtd I seem to have found a tentative answer to the question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278368/31669

Comment: POSIX specification for `cat` behavior: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cat.html

Comment: In `linkedin` testing, you have a question regarding `cat > notes -`. I get `cat: notes: No such file or directory`, but this is not an linkedin option. I did the command from an online `bash` editor, so probably in a offline `shell`, I can enter text which then flushes into `notes`.

Answer (score 22):

1. Instead of `echo hello > -`, you can use `echo hello > /dev/stdout`.

   While '-' is a convention that has to be implemented by each program wanting to support it, `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` are, when supported by the OS (at least Solaris, Linux and BSDs do), independent of the application and then will work as you intend.

Answer (score 14):

As [camh mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-for-argument-intended-for-filename/16364#16364), `-` is just a naming convention used by some programs. If you want to refer to these streams with a file descriptor the shell will recognize, [jiliagre was correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-for-argument-intended-for-filename/16377#16377) in having you use the name `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/stdout` instead. Those file names should work any place a normal file name would work.

1. That being said, your first example is kind of silly. Any output that would be caught by the redirect operator to write to a file is already ON standard-output, so redirecting it and writing it back to where it came from is useless. The behavior you use there is the pipe, not a redirect:

   ```
   echo hello |
   ```
2. In your second example you simply need to give can some indication that you want a litteral file of that name, not the internal alias it has. You can do this easiest by specifying a path to the file like this:

   ```
   cat ./-
   ```

Answer (score 6):

As for 1, the program has to support it. You can't just arbitrarily use it. As for 2, redirect input from (e.g., `cat < -`).

Answer (score 1):

The '-' approach has a lot of problems. First of all it requires an interpretation of the '-' character and many programs don't perform such interpretation. And furthermore, there are some programs that interpret an hyphen as a delimiter marking the end of command line options. The programs are written to work with filename arguments, the '-' approach is an hack, nice but weak.

The best way is:

```
$ echo hello > /dev/fd/1
```

`/dev/stdout` is a symbolik link of `/dev/fd/1`

Comment: The redirection is interpreted by the shell, not the program being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters have mostly two meanings:

> ASCII numeric chart.
>
> Scripting or symbolic.

It's possible that a single character represents a string, or act as a string. as my understanding.

in C language  `fopen()` function takes two arguments first file stream and the second mode in which file will be open. the mode is a string. even if it's single character.

cat > "-" works.