# sending output to /dev/stderr vs. >&2

Tags: portability, stderr

In scripts, errors are usually sent to file descriptor 2 with `&2`, ie:

```
echo "error" >&2
```

Sometimes `/dev/stderr` is used instead:

```
echo "error" > /dev/stderr
```

Looking at `/dev/stderr`, I see that it is only a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/2` , which in turn is a symlink to `/dev/pts/5` (on my current terminal).

Seems little bit over complicated. Is there some logic behind that ?

Is using `/dev/stderr` and `&2` equivalent ?

Is any of those preferred over the other ?

Comment: `echo "error" >2` creates a file with name `2` and content `error`.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36403/38906

Comment: I see my edit reintroduced &2 instead of 2. Is your question actually about the usage of `>2`, or `>&2`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The special device `/dev/stderr` is system-specific, while the file descriptor `2` (not the special device `/proc/self/fd/2`) is portable.  If you want to write non-portable code, those special devices are a good place to start.

There are a few systems with `/dev/stderr`: Linux, of course, and [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/stderr.4.html).  But OSX has no `/proc` filesystem, and its `/dev/stderr` is a link to `/dev/fd/2`.

Further reading:

- [Portability of “> /dev/stdout”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/portability-of-dev-stdout)
- [What method should I use to write error messages to 'stderr' using 'printf' in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963653/what-method-should-i-use-to-write-error-messages-to-stderr-using-printf-in-a)
- [patches/awk-dev-stderr](https://cygwin.com/ml/autoconf-patches/2000-q1/msg00973.html) (autoconf-patches)
- [Redirect stderr and stdout in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script)
- [Chapter 20. I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) (Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide)

Comment: Also there's the case where someone wants to do eg. this `2> bla.log` which would work as long as you pipe to `2` and not hard-code `/dev/stderr`. Basically `2` doesn't *need* to be the `stderr` output.

Comment: Moreover: on linux, write to _&2_ works for every user; write to _/dev/stderr_ works only for *root* users.

Comment: On MacOS, Debian and Fedora, each of the devices is owned by the current user, group `tty` with permissions 620 (making it writable by the user).

Answer (score 8):

In bash, and other shells, the way to redirect something *to* standard error is to use `>&2`. Bash opens `/dev/stderr` as the *file descriptor* `2`. File descriptors are referenced by `&N` where `N` is the number of the descriptor. So, `echo error >&2` will print `error` to standard error, to `/dev/stderr`.

It will also open `/dev/stdout` as file descriptor `1`. This means you can do `echo output >&1`. However, since everything is printed to standard output anyway by default, that is the same as `echo output` by itself.

Now, `2>` is different. Here, you are redirecting the error output of a command somewhere else. So, `2>file` means "redirect anything printed to file descriptor 2 (standard error) to `file`".

Answer (score 3):

You're right, `>&2` is more direct and perfectly "idiomatic".  They should be equivalent, so there's no particular reason to use `>/dev/stderr`.  Except that, if someone reading doesn't know what these do, one of them is probably easier to find out than the other :-).  But in general I'd suggest you use `>&2`.

/dev/stderr could be useful when programs will write errors to a specified filename, but don't support stderr.  Clearly this is a bit contrived; /dev/stdout is much more useful.  (I recently found the `mysql_safe` wrapper script won't write errors to the console; unfortunately it also wants to change the permissions on the error log file, so using /dev/stderr causes a few superfluous warnings).