# How to have find feature `-printf` print out into stderr

Tags: find, output

Is it possible somehow find feature `-printf` print out at the moment it's used into stderr ?

Comment: Could you give us a few more details about the use case here? Will `-printf` be the only thing that `find` will be outputting or will you combine it with something like `-ls` and you only want the `-printf` to go to stderr? I mean, are you just looking for `find . -printf '%f\n' 2>/dev/null`?

Answer (score 4):

Assumptions:

- GNU `find`;
- you don't want to redirect the stdout of `find` as a whole.

Then don't think `-printf` can be redirected. But there is `-fprintf`. Use it with [`/dev/stderr` or equivalent path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274044/108618).

> Action: `-fprintf file format`
> True; like `-printf` but write to `file` […]

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Print-File-Information.html#Print-File-Information))</sup>