# Can you clean up temporary files before they are used in shell?

Tags: shell-script

I want to avoid having temporary files laying around if my program crashes.

UNIX is wonderful in that you can keep a file open - even after you delete it.

So if you open the file, immediately delete it, and *then* do the slow processing, chances are high that even if you program crashes, the user will not have to clean up the file.

In shell I often see something similar to:

```
generate-the-file -o the-file
[...loads of other stuff that may use stdout or not...]
do_slow_processing < the-file
rm the-file
```

But if the program crashes before `rm` the user will have to clean up `the-file`.

In Perl you can do:

```
open(my $filehandle, "<", "the-file") || die;
unlink("the-file");
while(<$filehandle>) {
  # Do slow processing stuff here
  print;
}
close $filehandle;
```

Then the file is removed as soon as it is opened.

Is there a similar construct in shell?

Comment: You can keep a file open even after you **remove** it. It is deleted when the reference counters reach zero. You can't delete it (you can truncate it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is tested in csh, tcsh, sh, ksh, zsh, bash, ash, sash:

```
echo foo > the-file
(rm the-file; cat) < the-file | do_slow_processing
do_other_stuff
```

or if you prefer:

```
(rm the-file; do_slow_processing) < the-file
do_other_stuff
```

Interestingly, it also works for fifos:

```
mkfifo the-fifo
(rm the-fifo; cat) < the-fifo | do_slow_processing &
echo foo > the-fifo
```

This is because the reader is blocked until something is written.

Comment: Or just `f=$(mktemp); exec 3<"$f" 4>"$f"; rm "$f"; ... use >&3 and <&4 instead of >"$f" or <"$f" ...`

Comment: For fifos you can use `f=$(mktemp -u); mkfifo "$f"; exec 3<>"$f" 3<"$f" 4>"$f"; rm "$f"; ...` which doesn't block, and doesn't require background commands.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding 3 and 4 can you make those variables, so you just get an unused file descriptor? Otherwise you would have to remember which number is used for what.

Comment: Do they work in `csh` and `sh`?

Comment: They work in any bourne shell (except for the `$(...)` which you would have to replace with `\`...\`` in pre-posix shells). You could use variables, but only in ksh-like shells (bash, zsh, etc). `exec {f}<file; echo >&"$f"`, etc.

Comment: Where'd you get `csh` to test it?

Comment: sorry @S.S.Anne , I was facetious. there's a link at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell

Comment: This looks like a UUOC (useless use of `cat`).  `do_slow_processing < the-fifo & rm the-fifo` would be simple but I'm not 100% sure it's safe.  But `(do_slow_processing &) < the-fifo; rm the-fifo` would be; the redirect has to happen before forking a subshell and moving on to the rm.  Or maybe with `{ do_slow_processing & } < the-fifo`.  Or I think `exec < the-fifo` would work if you don't mind replacing stdin.

Answer (score 1):

```
generate-the-file > the-file
exec 5< the-file
rm the-file
...
do_slow_processing 0<&5
```

Notes:

- You need to run exec with no executable, so it affects the descriptors of the shell itself
- Only up to fd 9 available
- You could use /proc/self/fd/X if you need a filename. This interface is not portable between UNIX flavors (it probably works for you, though).
- Trying to read again the fd (e.g. two calls to `cat 0<&5`) will fail as you are at EOF. You would need to rewind it, or overcome it by reading via `/proc/self/fd/X`
- In most cases liek above you could do without an actual file, though and do a simple `generate-the-file | do_slow_processing`

‎

**Update:**

The OP mentions that `generate-the-file` may not produce its output in stdout. There are a few idioms for this:

- Specify an output file of `-`. It is customary to accept an output filename of - to mean stdout. This is [acknowledged by POSIX.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02):

  > **Guideline 13:**
  >   For utilities that use operands to represent files to be opened for either reading or writing, the '-' operand should be used to mean only standard input (or standard output when it is clear from context that an output file is being specified) or a file named -.

(for utilities other than those where they explicitly define that, it is implementatio-defined, but there is a good chance that it is supported by your `generate-the-file` tool)

- Use `/dev/stdout` or `/proc/self/fd/1`. OS dependant, see [How portable are /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36403/70346)
- Use process substitution. bash will allow you to write `>(process substitution)` as a filename. For example:

  > wget -O >(rot13 > question.txt) https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/579535/70346

This won't work on all shells and requires OS support for fd filenames.

Comment: Often `generate-the-file` does not send data to stdout, so the simple pipe will often not be a possibility.

Comment: The question asked about a case of `generate-the-file > the-file`. I assumed there was a good reason for that, such as the-file needing to be seekable, but did not want to skip the basic answer of `generate-the-file | do_slow_processing` since it is what most readers should be using. I have expanded the answer with some options for when `generate-the-file` does not send its output on stdout, but lets you specify a filename.

Answer (score 1):

In the `bash` shell, the way to handle clean-up is by using the EXIT `trap` builtin (from within a `bash` shell, type `help trap`):

```
trap 'rm temp-file' EXIT
```

This feature also exists in the `dash` shell, frequently aliased to `sh` in modern linux distributions.

Comment: Would that also work if, say, the shell is killed -9?

Comment: @OleTange: My testing shows that it does not work for `kill -9`, but does work for `kill -15` and `C-c`.