# What does the symbol '-' mean in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, io

I see this symbol all the time and my book has yet to clarify what it means. None of the man pages or web searches clarify this either. At first I believed it to be a I/O symbol, but that never works when I try to play with it.

For example, in the `patch` Man and Info documents, it say

> You can also specify where to read the patch from with the '-i
>   PATCHFILE' or '--input=PATCHFILE' option. If you do not specify
>   PATCHFILE, or if PATCHFILE is `'-'`, 'path' reads the patch (that is,
>   the 'diff' output) from the standard input.

When ever I see the '-' symbol, it is almost followed (at some point) by some mention of standard input.

What am I missing here? Does this symbol reference standard input? What does '-' mean in the context of Bash?

Comment: It's a string that `patch` chose to give a meaning to (encouraged [by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)); it has no innate meaning. I know there's a duplicate of this question around, but "-" is a nightmare to search for. I will try to find it.

Comment: Also relevant: [Is `-` used only with cd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146913/is-used-only-with-cd/146918#146918)

Comment: you're right in the fact that it is a nightmare to search for. I figured someone at some point had to ask it, but nothing was showing up.

Comment: @user147135 '-'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash doesn't interpret a `-` argument at all. It is merely a convention implemented by many programs.

You usually see it when a program normally works on files, so they need some text string that isn't likely to be a file name to use when you want it to work on [`stdin`/`stdout`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) instead.

It is highly unlikely that you will run into a system with a file purposely named `-`, because that's the standard [option character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_option) on Unix. But, because it is in fact legal to name a file `-` — or more generally any file *beginning* with `-` — many programs that understand a `-` argument *also* understand the option `--`, meaning "stop processing options." This lets you do things like remove a file called `-`:

```
$ rm -- -
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge this is not a bash construct but a convention.
Apps use `-` to denote reading from stdin or write to stdout in lieu of an actual file or writing /dev/stdin /dev/stdout.