# function of "crontab -"

Tags: scripting, cron, pipe

I'm writing a bash script which, among other things, will edit crontab on another server. The way I figured out how to do this is with:

```
crontab -l | sed <stuff> | crontab -
```

It does what I need it to do, but I'm still not sure how. What exactly does "crontab -" do? When I run it by itself from the shell, it takes over the shell until I hit ctl+c, but doesn't seem to do anything. Is its only purpose to overwrite cron contents with whatever's passed from stdin? I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Comment: this is cool - i'm going use this one day to update cron.  very useful.

Comment: Note that this is a common enough idiom that on debian(-derived) systems, the [`man` page for `crontab(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/cron/crontab.1.en.html) includes notice about the handling of system default warning comments when using `crontab -l | crontab -`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does '-' work in bash redirection?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417377/how-does-work-in-bash-redirection)

Comment: Personally I would prefer something like `crontab -l >.crontab; sed ... .crontab | crontab`, which would leave me a copy of the original in case my `sed` command mangled the data irrecoverably.

Comment: @roaima I've already got that functionality in the command, using tee to save a copy of crontab. I just left it out for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One syntax for crontab is

> crontab <file>

Per [Usage of dash (-) in place of a filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename#answer-16364) your usage of the `-` is to take **stdin** which in this case is the **stdout** coming from `sed` which is then feeding in to replace the <file> argument and replace the contents of cron *instead of from the file you are giving it* the **stdin** that is acting as that file.

Comment: This is exactly the information I was looking for. Makes sense now why I couldn't find it in the cron documentation. Thanks!

Comment: One final missing part is to note that the `crontab` command does not replace any of its cron data until it has received everything from _stdin_. (So if you start typing, and then Ctrl/C out, you haven't lost the previous/current data.) This is peculiar to `crontab` and the idiom `cat <file | sed ... | cat >file` does _not hold true_ in the general sense.