# Portable way to invoke tar with a list of files from stdin

Tags: io-redirection, tar, busybox, stdin, options

I want to create a .tgz from the content of a directory. I also want to strip the leading "`./`" from the tar'ed content.
I had done this as follows:

```
cd /path/to/files/ && find . -type f | cut -c 3- | xargs czf /path/to/tgz/myTgz.tgz
```

I [learned recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016035/does-tar-exit-code-123-always-mean-empty-archive) that using `xargs` may not be the best way to pull this off because `xargs` may invoke `tar` multiple times if the cmdline arg list gets too long, and I was advised to make use of `tar`'s ability to read a list of input files from stdin. I ended up finding [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597875/how-can-i-build-a-tar-from-stdin) on how to do this. However, I find that the recommendation...

```
cd /path/to/files/ && find . -type f | cut -c 3- | tar czf foo.tgz -T -
```

...seems to not be portable. It runs fine on my dev PC, but on a busybox target, I get the following error from running the same command:

```
tar: can't open '-': No such file or directory
```

So, my **question**: is there a truly portable/global way to invoke `tar` to create a `.tgz` by feeding it input files from stdin (as opposed to cmdline arguments)?

(It is not an option available to me to install alternatives to `tar` such as `gnutar`/`bsdtar`/etc.)

(Secondary question: Why does the "`-T -`" argument to `tar` denote "*read files from `stdin`*"? From the `tar` man page, all I could find was that "`-T`" means:

> get names to extract or create from FILE

... but I couldn't see any reference to a plain "`-`")

Comment: See [Usage of dash (-) in place of a filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename).

Comment: Since `tar` is not a POSIX utility, a truly portable (as in "standard") implementation may not be found.  `pax`, on the other hand, is a POSIX utility.

Comment: This site does one question per question, and that tertiary question is a massive distraction that is a question in its own right, most likely already long since covered.

Comment: @JdeBP - removed tertiary question

Comment: @Kusalananda - that's an informative comment; thank you. However, it looks like `pax` isn't available in Busybox (at least in the version of Busybox I have to work with). I think I may have to resign myself to using the sub-optimal approach using `xargs`.

Comment: @Kusalananda `pax` is portable in the sense of standard, but not portable in the sense of being part of the busybox suite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a common convention to interpret `-` to mean standard input where an input file name is expected, and to mean standard output where an output file name is expected. Because this is a common convention, the short help summary in the GNU tar man page does not mention it, but the [complete manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/files.html#SEC108) (usually available locally through `info tar`) does. The [POSIX command line utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) includes this convention, so it's pretty widespread (but it's always a choice on the part of the author of the program).

BusyBox utilities do follow this convention. But the [manual](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#tar) does not mention `tar` as supporting the option `-T`, and neither does the version on the machine I'm posting this (1.27.2 on Ubuntu). I don't know why you're getting the error “: No such file or directory” rather than “invalid option -- 'T'”. It seems that your `tar` interprets `-T` as an option that does not take an argument, then sees `-` as a file name. Since in this context tar needs a *file name* to put in the archive, and not just some *content* that comes from a file, it would not make sense to use the stdin/stdout interpretation for `-`.

BusyBox utilities support a restricted set of functionality by design, because they're intended for embedded systems where the fancier features of GNU utilities wouldn't fit. Apparently `-T` is not a feature that the BusyBox designers considered useful.

I don't think BusyBox tar has any way to read file names from stdin. If you need to archive a subset of the files in a directory and you don't need any symbolic links in the archive, a workaround is to create a forest of symbolic links in a temporary directory and archive this temporary directory.

It's not clear exactly why you're using `find`. If you only want the files in the current directory, why not `tar czf /path/to/archive.tgz -- *` ? Your command does make sense if there are subdirectories and you want to archive the files in these subdirectories, but not the directories themselves (presumably to restore them in a place where the directory structure must exist but may have different permissions). In this case a leading `./` wouldn't do any harm.

Answer (score 6):

I know that is a stupid answer and maybe not good for you but how bad is if you just...

```
cd /path/to/files/ && find . -type f | cut -c 3- >/tmp/temp.txt 
tar czf foo.tgz -T /tmp/temp.txt
```

Comment: Not at all a stupid answer. The original question (and the reason why I asked if this was possible to do this from `stdin`) was because of the problem I noted RE: `xargs` calling `tar` multiple times if the input list is too long...does this solution also bypass that problem? (it seems like it does because it's also using "`-T`", not explicitly putting the source files as _command-line arguments_)

Comment: The one problem with this script that I see is if you run two of them in the same time, in this case you will need to use something to generate random names for temp.txt....

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-u/--update` option in conjunction with `xargs`.
I just tried and to prove that it works, I gave the filename arguments to `tar` one-by-one using `xargs -n 1`:

`find top_of_tree/ -type f | xargs -n 1 tar -uf archive.tar`

Of course, this is just a proof of concept. In your case, it is probably more practical to allow `xargs` to separate the argument list into larger parts that do not exceed the argument length limit, so as to avoid having a lot of calls to `tar`:

`find top_of_tree/ -type f | xargs tar -uf archive.tar`

The prerequisite is that all implementations of `tar` on your platforms support at least one of the `-u/--update` flags.

EDIT: the `-u/--update` flags allow `tar` to create as well as append to an archive.

I just noticed that unfortunately, you cannot update compressed archives (tgz, created with the `-c` flag). However, you can, by all means create a non-compressed archive first and then compress the results.

Also, it should not confuse you that I'm using flags to `tar` with a hyphen ('-' character). It accepts both forms. In my example, `-uf` would be equivalent to `uf` in yours.

As for the `-` option, it is probalby not documented in the man page of `tar` because it is a very common Unix convention for command line tools that deal with streams as well as named files.
`-` is usually a special argument for filters and names the standard input stream as a file.

Comment: Good idea, thank you, but unfortunately, looks like Busybox version of `tar` does not support `-u`/`-update`.

Comment: I worked a lot on embedded machines with BusyBox as well. Unfortunately, my only solution was to cross-compile 7Zip for that system.

Comment: `-u` wouldn't work with a gzipped archive anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This post was helpful, but here's a real-world example for where I only wanted to backup the folder structure in a particular file system, and wanted tar to read said folder structure from stdin:

```
find /kelinda/ -type d | tar cvf /tmp/kelinda.folders.tar --no-recursion -T -
```

Note:  /kelinda is just a file system that I have which exists on an external hard drive.

So you can use find to find to get a list of exactly what you want and pipe that into tar.  The "-T -" will read input files from stdin (as stated in other posts), then I added the "--no-recursion" to prevent tar from backing up other files that I didn't want.

In other words, using find, along with the --no-recursion option, gives you a way to backup an exact list of files and/or folders and then combining that with the "-T -" option allows you to read said list of input from stdin.