# SCP fails without error

Tags: scp

I've been experiencing very strange behavior of SCP for some time: whenever I try to copy a file, the output of SCP contains a bunch of underscores and the file is not copied.

```
$ scp test.txt 192.168.0.2:~
job@192.168.0.2's password: 
 ________________________________________
```

When I create an SSH connection using Midnight Commander and copy files it does work.

Some info about my machine:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010

$ uname -a
Linux squatpc 2.6.38-10-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 15:05:41 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

And I'm running Kubuntu 11.04.

**Edit:** Some more info as requested by the comments:

```
$ scp -v test.txt 192.168.0.2:~
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.0.2, user (unspecified), command scp -v -t -- ~
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.2 [192.168.0.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/job/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/job/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/job/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/job/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/job/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/job/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 28:f3:2b:31:36:43:9b:07:d8:33:ca:43:4f:ca:6c:4c
debug1: Host '192.168.0.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/job/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/job/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/job/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/job/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
job@192.168.0.2's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.0.2 ([192.168.0.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t -- ~
 ________________________________________
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2120, received 1872 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7783.1, received 6872.6
debug1: Exit status 0
```

and

```
$ type scp
scp is hashed (/usr/bin/scp)
```

Comment: Try with -v to get some debugging info during the copy.

Comment: Also, just in case... What is the output of `type scp`?

Comment: @EightBitTony: see my edits.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: see my edits too:-)

Comment: If you do `ssh 192.168.0.2 echo hello`, do you get any output other than `hello`?

Comment: @Gilles: apart from the password prompt, no, just `hello`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Ok LOL, I just figured out what the problem is.

Since I like cows so much, I've put `fortune | cowsay` at the top of my `.bashrc` file which produces output like the following when starting `bash`:

```
 _______________________________________
< You will lose an important disk file. >
 ---------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

This is all fine (and sometimes funny) when running `bash` interactively. However, bash reads `~/.bashrc` when it is interactive and not a login shell, *or when it is a login shell and its parent process is `rshd` or `sshd`*. When you run `scp`, the server starts a shell which starts a remote `scp` instance. The output from `.bashrc` confuses `scp` because it is sent the same way the `scp` protocol data is sent. This is apparently a known bug, see [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20527) for more details.

Also note that the underscores I mentioned in the question are those in the top line of the text balloon.

So the solution was simple: I put the following at the top of `.bashrc` on the remote (destination) machine:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return
```

This line is present in the default `.bashrc` but was put way down because of my many (apparently careless) edits.

Comment: `echo "don't have a cow" | cowsay`

Comment: Wow, after months of scp just being broken, you finally illuminated the answer for me. I would have never thought of this. I just did a `mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak` to test and make sure that was the problem, and it worked after I did that.

Comment: @ScottStensland This needs to go at the top of the remote `.bashrc`. The local one is irrelevant. Note that there was a typo in my comment (the answer is correct): it's `*i*`, not `*-*`.

Comment: NO NO NO. rtfm. bashrc is run for non-interactive shells. If you want happy cow messages when you login change your bash_profile. If you want cow wisdom every time you open a X-Window then try to work out if this is one of *MANY* scenarios in which you should not be writing the terminal - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-can-i-detect-if-the-shell-is-controlled-from-ssh

Comment: Saved my bacon. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, the right way to enable un-hindered `scp` is less about which conditional for stdout in your `~/.bashrc` script, and more about simply restricting screen output to the `~/.bash_profile` script.  At least that is how it works for my distro (CentOS.)

Edit for clarity:

1. Put only lines in your ~/.bashrc file as required by "all" remote conections (i.e. setting certain ENV vars is OK, but echoing human-readable text is not.)
2. YMMV

Comment: mind expounding?  i.e. how to restrict screen output to the .bash-profile ?

Comment: By `screen` output, I mean `echo "Greetings, Master"` or anything else that displays output to the terminal window.  Don't put that in your ~/.bashrc --keep it in your ~/.bash_profile script.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior might occur when your `.bashrc` file produce some output or you have `MOTD(Message Of The Day)`.You can use the `-o` option with `scp`:

With `-o` you can pass options to SSH, in this case you can give option like `RequestTTY=no` and it never requests terminal output.

```
scp -o RequestTTY=no source target
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Alright. I'll make a little bit understandable.

Answer (score 0):

@Job is right. However, this problem might become a bigger issue when the welcome screen graphic is part of `/etc/bash.bashrc`

You will have to make sure you clear such welcome graphic content from both:

1. /etc/bash.bashrc
2. ~/.bashrc

On debian & ubuntu systems, on a non-interactive shell, /etc/bash.bashrc is first called before ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with this error at scp, it is long time ago, when I used it. I replaced scp with rsync and it is much better. Rsync should be at almost evere Linux device.

I wrote about rsync here, in tread about scp:
[How can I best copy large numbers of small files over scp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/how-can-i-best-copy-large-numbers-of-small-files-over-scp/736859)

Rsync is described there by post from JohnU.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/438007)