# scp from remote host fails due to login greeting set in .bashrc

Tags: prompt, scp, bashrc

My simple file `scp` from a remote host (actually a locally run VM but that shouldn't matter) failed without displaying any error message but clearly not having copied the desired file:

`scp myuser@myhost:~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.ubuntu`

The only thing it displayed was

`================================================================================`

I thought that was peculiar because that was the first line displayed in my login greeting on the remote, which looks like:

```
================================================================================
Welcome to <Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS>
You are <myuser> logged into <hostname> (my_ipaddress)
Today is <Wed Aug 28 16:48:49 EDT 2013>
================================================================================
```

And here are the contents of the `.bashrc` on the remote that define that greeting:

```
1 if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
2     . ~/.bash_aliases
3 fi
4 
5 
6 export PS1='\w@\t>'
7 
8 set -o vi
9 
10 printf %80s |tr " " "="
11 echo
12 
13 echo "Welcome to <"`lsb_release -d | sed 's/Description\:\s*//'`">"
14 
15 export IPADDR=`hostname -I`
16 
17 echo "You are <"$LOGNAME"> logged into <"$HOSTNAME"> ("$IPADDR")"
18 
19 echo "Today is <"`date`">"
20 
21 
22 printf %80s |tr " " "="
23 echo
```

Once I removed everything from like 9 down on the remote .bashrc, the scp succeeded.

Can anyone expound on this peculiar occurrence?  The local host is `Mac OS Mountain Lion` and the remote (VM) is `Ubuntu 12.04`.

Answer (score 7):

Helped by [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18231/scp-fails-without-error), I figured that the special characters in the greeting were the problem and that the `.bashrc` should just return unless we are in the interactive mode.  So I added the following to the beginning of .bashrc on the remote:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
if [[ $- != *i* ]]; then return; fi
```

Which solved the problem and I was able to use `scp`

Comment: As mentioned on the duplicate thread: not `[ -z "$PS1" ]`, it doesn't reliably test for an interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

yes, if your remote shell is chatty when you ssh, scp will fail as it depends on a clear ssh connection. here is a more detailed explanation.

https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works